# Updating Lead Info in marketo

Tags: marketo

Initially, I associate the lead when the user signs up to our app on a 14 days trial period.

```
function associateMarketoLead() {
 if (window.marketoKey)) {
  if (typeof Munchkin !== 'undefined') {
   if ('function' === typeof Munchkin.munchkinFunction) {
    let leadAttributes = {
      Email: user.email,
      accountId: accountId,
      LeadSource: 'Web'
    };

    Munchkin.munchkinFunction('associateLead', leadAttributes, marketoKey);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

We use marketo to send email campaigns at the end of 14-days trial. But, for certain leads, we extend the trial period and so we want to update the lead's database with trial extended date. How can I do that ? I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
function notifyMarketoOnTrialExtension(accountId, trialExtendedDate) {
 if (window.marketoKey) {
  if (typeof Munchkin !== 'undefined') {
   if ('function' === typeof Munchkin.munchkinFunction) {
    var leadAttributes = {
      Email: user.email,
      accountId: accountId,
      trialExtendedDate: trialExtendedDate
    };

    Munchkin.munchkinFunction('associateLead', leadAttributes, window.marketoKey);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This small snippet shows you how to invoke `associateLead` with the correct key (third parameter), which is an `SHA1` hash of your private key concatenated with the email of the lead you are trying to associate. In your example you are just sending the private key as third parameter.

I used this library for calculating the SHA1 hash `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/2.0.2/sha1.js`

```
var email = 'user@domain.com';
var shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-1', 'TEXT');
shaObj.update('<your-munchkin-private-key-goes-here>' + email);
var hash = shaObj.getHash('HEX');
Munchkin.init('<your-munchkin-identifier-goes-here>');
Munchkin.munchkinFunction('associateLead', { 'Email': email }, hash);
```

Hope it helps.

Alejo.