# Can I create a contact in Eloqua from javascript?

Tags: javascript, marketo, eloqua

Is there a way to create a contact in Eloqua directly from the javascript in my web page (rather than using a backend REST API call)?

I can do this in Marketo with their munchkin javascript library by calling `associateLead` as described in this question: [Updating Lead Info in marketo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030183/updating-lead-info-in-marketo), and am curious if there is a similar way to do this for Eloqua.

Answer (score 2):

CORS is not enabled in Eloqua.
You'll have to use a backend call to:

- The Rest API to create a single contact: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/api-Application-2.0-Contacts.html
- The Bulk API to create multiple contacts: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-bulk-2.0-contacts-imports-post.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

One way to create a contact directly on a web page is using a [blind form submit](https://community.oracle.com/message/13810485#13810485).

Here is an [AJAX example](https://community.oracle.com/message/14068502#14068502).